# admin_consent for openid connect and dynamic scopes

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-graph-api

We have a webapplication that uses openid connect, with azure as the identityprovider, to sign in users. So users, when signing in is sent to a URL like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id=3{clientId}&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8765/ms/oidc/signon/response&scope=openid+profile+https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state=1234&nonce={nonce}
```

this works fine, but requires users to consent to our apps permission scopes the first time they use it.

We'd like to offer office365 administrators the ability to consent on behalf of their entire tenant, so we send them to an endpoint like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={clientId}&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8765
```

this also seems to work fine, and the admin i informed that they will consent on behalf of all users in their tenant. However, the user is still presented with the consent prompt on first login. 
This does make sense, since the app is only registered with the user.read permission, so if we instead sent the user to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientId}&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8765/ms/oidc/signon/response&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state={state}&nonce={nonce}
```

without the dynamic permission request, and response type only set to token, the admin consent works, and users are not presented with the consent prompt. 
So, I guess I have 2 questions:

1) is this how it's supposed to work, or is there some way to grant admin consent to the profile and openid scopes?

2) Am I actually missing anything by not requesting these(openid+profile) permissions? I don't receive and id_token in the response, but is seems the authentication_token already contains even more information than the id_token does anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1) is this how it's supposed to work, or is there some way to grant admin consent to the profile and openid scopes?

It seems a bug in azure ad v2.0 consent framework , well-known scopes(openid,profile) should be granted by default when you do admin permissions. Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2/issues/2) .

> > 2) Am I actually missing anything by not requesting these(openid+profile) permissions? I don't receive and id_token in the response, but is seems the authentication_token already contains even more information than the id_token does anyway

You don't use OpenID connect since you haven't added the openid scope ,so id_token is not returned . But since you have the user.read permission of microsoft graph api , you could use microsoft graph api to read the user's basic information . Id_token and access token are different ,the id_token is used to identify the authenticated user. The access_token is used to prove access rights to protected resources . Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, guess I'll have to wait for MS to fix it. 

And regarding point 2, I do understand the difference between oauth and openid connect, we're currently using the openid connect scopes and do get id_tokens, so my questions was more along the lines of, if there's anything gained by using oidc in this context, since, as you point out, we're already requesting user.read,